# How to fix 'getting no response from write characteristic in bluetooth le'?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm learning bluetooth le on Android and have run into the problem of not being able to get a response from a write characteristic. The hardware that I'm using is an HM-10 which has a service and characteristic which I'm able to write to - something that I'm sure is about the code i've written.

I have followed the article on android developer for setting up bluetooth gatt. The callback contains onDescriptorRead/Write, onCharacteristicRead/Write, onServicesDiscovered, onCharacteristicChanged including the broadcast receiver for updating information from service to the activity. I've also tried to plug in the HM-10 to my computer and am using RealTerm to send data from my phone app. I confirm that the data that i'm sending is getting through. But when sending the data from the computer through the HM-10 i get no information back from my phone app. (on the onCharacteristicChanged, or onCharacteristicRead) Before doing the sending I am modifying the notification setting on the characteristic to enabled.

The descriptor is CCCD (0x2902)
The characteristic is a custom one that according to documentation handles READ, WRITE, NOTIFY. To be frank I do not know how to check this in code.

The command to send to characteristic.

```
if (characteristic.equals("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")) {
  characteristic.setValue("AT+CSQ?");
}
bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

The callback for write

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
Log.w(TAG, "successfully wrote characteristic");

broadcastWrite(ACTION_WRITE_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
}
}
```

The callback for read characteristic

```
@Override
// Result of a characteristic read operation
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);

}
}
```

the callback for characteristic changed

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
Log.w(TAG, "successfully received new characteristic change");
BroadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
}
```

The command for enabling notification on characteristic

```
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
 bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

I'm expecting that the bluetooth gatt is set up to handle characteristic changes. What actually happens is a big black hole with no responses.

Comment: Doing a bit more research found that the property is set to READ, WRITE_NO_RESPONSE and NOTIFY. I've done a bit of research into using WRITE_NO_RESPONSE and it said that responses were made through notification. Ive done some research about the setCharacteristicNotification method (i do not have this line in my program) but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Upon researching further, using setCharacteristicNotification in combination with a change to the Notification setting on the CCCD descriptor has successfully solved the problem.